# Problem with Graphics3D and opacity in 11.1.1

Tags: graphics3d, rendering

When an opacity option is added to a 3D object, all 3D object looked blurry.

Operating system: Windows 10 64 bit. Mathematica Version: 10.4.1 and 11.1.1.

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 1}}],
 {Opacity[0], Tetrahedron[]}}]
```

Comment: I can reproduce this result with the same versions of Mathematica and Windows.  However, I can see a small difference between the four lines with `Opacity[0]` and `Opacity[1]` even for Version 10.4.1.